# How do I expose custom files similar to /procfs on Linux?

Tags: c, linux, in-memory, procfs

I have a *writer* process which outputs its status at regular intervals as a readable *chunck* of `wchar_t`.
I would need to ensure the following properties:

1. When there's and update, the readers *shouldn't* read partial/corrupted data
2. The file should be volatile in memory so that when the writer quits, the file is gone
3. The file content size is variable
4. Multiple readers could read the file in parallel, doesn't matter if the content is synced, as long as is non partial for each client
5. If using `truncate` and then `write`, clients should only read the full file and not observe such partial operations

How could I implement such */procfs*-like file, outside */procfs* filesystem?

I was thinking to use classic c *Linux* file APIs and create something under */dev/shm* by default, but I find it hard to implement effectively point 1 and 5 most of all.
How could I expose such file?

Comment: you can create a filesystem driver or you can explore using [libfuse](https://github.com/libfuse/libfuse) which would be simpler

Comment: Can't create a driver, this needs to run in userspace

Comment: you can also use pipe (see [`mkfifo`](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/mkfifo.3.html))

Comment: With potentially multiple readers? How would you reccomend to use it? Any more details?

Comment: So what you're saying is that you need some sort of copy-on-write resource. That sounds like a process, offering the data over a pipe or socket, keeping track of every client. In another approach, I don't think you could do this with an actual file, but you might be able to pull this off with the write process spawning mmapped memory. It then becomes a problem of time and efficiency.

Comment: @Cheatah I need something like _/proc/self/maps_, where other processes can easily read it, never disappears (as long as the process is alive) and whatnot. I wouldn't want to use sockets/pipes nor mmap, where I have to have one or more consumers, I would really want to do something like _/procfs_ ... simply output a file and if there's one or more readers, they can look at it without the file being truncated. Don't care if one or more reader are reading outdated info.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Typical solution is to create a new file in the same directory, then rename (hardlink) it over the old one.

This way, processes see either an old one or a new one, never a mix; and it only depends on the moment when they open the file.

The Linux kernel takes care of the caching, so if the file is accessed often, it will be in RAM (page cache).  The writer must, however, remember to delete the file when it exits.

---

A better approach is to use [fcntl()](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/fcntl.2.html)-based advisory record locks (typically over the entire file, i.e. `.l_whence = SEEK_SET`, `.l_start = 0`, `.l_len = 0`).

The writer will grab a write/exclusive lock before truncating and rewriting the contents, and readers a read/shared lock before reading the contents.

This requires cooperation, however, and the writer must be prepared to not be able to lock (or grabbing the lock may take undefined amount of time).

---

A Linux-only scheme would be to use atomic replacement (via rename/hardlinking), and file leases.

(When the writer process has an exclusive lease on an open file, it gets a signal whenever another process wants to open that same file (inode, not file name).  It has at least a few seconds to downgrade or release the lease, at which point the opener gets access to the contents.)

Basically, the writer process creates an empty status file, and obtains exclusive lease on it.  Whenever the writer receives a signal that a reader wants to access the status file, it writes the current status to the file, releases the lease, creates a new empty file in the same directory (same mount suffices) as the status file, obtains an exclusive lease on that one, and renames/hardlinks it over the status file.

If the status file contents do not change all the time, only periodically, then the writer process creates an empty status file, and obtains exclusive lease on it.  Whenever the writer receives a signal that a reader wants to access the (empty) status file, it writes the current status to the file, and releases the lease.  Then, when the writer process' status is updated, and there is no lease yet, it creates a new empty file in the status file directory, takes an exclusive lease on it, and renames/hardlinks over the status file.

This way, the status file is always updated just before a reader opens it, and only then.  If there are multiple readers at the same time, they can open the status file without interruption when the writer releases the lease.

It is important to note that the status information should be collected in a single structure or similar, so that writing it out to the status file is efficient.  Leases are automatically broken if not released soon enough (but there are a few seconds at least to react), and the lease is on the inode – file contents – not the file name, so we still need the atomic replacement.

Here's a crude example implementation:

```
#define _POSIX_C_SOURCE  200809L
#define _GNU_SOURCE
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdarg.h>
#include <inttypes.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <fcntl.h>
#include <pthread.h>
#include <signal.h>
#include <limits.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <errno.h>

#define   LEASE_SIGNAL  (SIGRTMIN+0)

static pthread_mutex_t  status_lock = PTHREAD_MUTEX_INITIALIZER;
static int              status_changed = 0;
static size_t           status_len = 0;
static char            *status = NULL;

static pthread_t        status_thread;
static char            *status_newpath = NULL;
static char            *status_path = NULL;
static int              status_fd = -1;
static int              status_errno = 0;

char *join2(const char *src1, const char *src2)
{
    const size_t  len1 = (src1) ? strlen(src1) : 0;
    const size_t  len2 = (src2) ? strlen(src2) : 0;
    char         *dst;

    dst = malloc(len1 + len2 + 1);
    if (!dst) {
        errno = ENOMEM;
        return NULL;
    }

    if (len1 > 0)
        memcpy(dst, src1, len1);
    if (len2 > 0)
        memcpy(dst+len1, src2, len2);
    dst[len1+len2] = '\0';

    return dst;
}

static void *status_worker(void *payload __attribute__((unused)))
{
    siginfo_t info;
    sigset_t  mask;
    int       err, num;

    /* This thread blocks all signals except LEASE_SIGNAL. */
    sigfillset(&mask);
    sigdelset(&mask, LEASE_SIGNAL);
    err = pthread_sigmask(SIG_BLOCK, &mask, NULL);
    if (err)
        return (void *)(intptr_t)err;

    /* Mask for LEASE_SIGNAL. */
    sigemptyset(&mask);
    sigaddset(&mask, LEASE_SIGNAL);

    /* This thread can be canceled at any cancellation point. */
    pthread_setcanceltype(PTHREAD_CANCEL_DEFERRED, NULL);
    pthread_setcancelstate(PTHREAD_CANCEL_ENABLE, NULL);

    while (1) {
        num = sigwaitinfo(&mask, &info);
        if (num == -1 && errno != EINTR)
            return (void *)(intptr_t)errno;

        /* Ignore all but the lease signals related to the status file. */
        if (num != LEASE_SIGNAL || info.si_signo != LEASE_SIGNAL || info.si_fd != status_fd)
            continue;

        /* We can be canceled at this point safely. */
        pthread_testcancel();

        /* Block cancelability for a sec, so that we maintain the mutex correctly. */
        pthread_setcancelstate(PTHREAD_CANCEL_DISABLE, NULL);

        pthread_mutex_lock(&status_lock);        
        status_changed = 0;

        /* Write the new status to the file. */
        if (status && status_len > 0) {
            const char        *ptr = status;
            const char *const  end = status + status_len;
            ssize_t            n;

            while (ptr < end) {
                n = write(status_fd, ptr, (size_t)(end - ptr));
                if (n > 0) {
                    ptr += n;
                } else
                if (n != -1) {
                    if (!status_errno)
                        status_errno = EIO;
                    break;
                } else
                if (errno != EINTR) {
                    if (!status_errno)
                        status_errno = errno;
                    break;
                }
            }
        }

        /* Close and release lease. */
        close(status_fd);
        status_fd = -1;

        /* After we release the mutex, we can be safely canceled again. */
        pthread_mutex_unlock(&status_lock);
        pthread_setcancelstate(PTHREAD_CANCEL_ENABLE, NULL);

        pthread_testcancel();
    }
}

static int start_status_worker(void)
{
    sigset_t          mask;
    int               result;
    pthread_attr_t    attrs;

    /* This thread should block LEASE_SIGNAL signals. */
    sigemptyset(&mask);
    sigaddset(&mask, LEASE_SIGNAL);
    result = pthread_sigmask(SIG_BLOCK, &mask, NULL);
    if (result)
        return errno = result;

    /* Create the worker thread. */
    pthread_attr_init(&attrs);
    pthread_attr_setstacksize(&attrs, 2*PTHREAD_STACK_MIN);
    result = pthread_create(&status_thread, &attrs, status_worker, NULL);
    pthread_attr_destroy(&attrs);

    /* Ready. */
    return 0;
}

int set_status(const char *format, ...)
{
    va_list  args;
    char    *new_status = NULL;
    int      len;

    if (!format)
        return errno = EINVAL;

    va_start(args, format);
    len = vasprintf(&new_status, format, args);
    va_end(args);
    if (len < 0)
        return errno = EINVAL;

    pthread_mutex_lock(&status_lock);
    free(status);
    status = new_status;
    status_len = len;
    status_changed++;

    /* Do we already have a status file prepared? */
    if (status_fd != -1 || !status_newpath) {
        pthread_mutex_unlock(&status_lock);
        return 0;
    }

    /* Prepare the status file. */
    do {
        status_fd = open(status_newpath, O_WRONLY | O_CREAT | O_CLOEXEC, 0666);
    } while (status_fd == -1 && errno == EINTR);
    if (status_fd == -1) {
        pthread_mutex_unlock(&status_lock);
        return 0;
    }

    /* In case of failure, do cleanup. */
    do {
        /* Set lease signal. */
        if (fcntl(status_fd, F_SETSIG, LEASE_SIGNAL) == -1)
            break;

        /* Get exclusive lease on the status file. */
        if (fcntl(status_fd, F_SETLEASE, F_WRLCK) == -1)
            break;

        /* Replace status file with the new, leased one. */
        if (rename(status_newpath, status_path) == -1)
            break;

        /* Success. */
        pthread_mutex_unlock(&status_lock);
        return 0;
    } while (0);

    if (status_fd != -1) {
        close(status_fd);
        status_fd = -1;
    }
    unlink(status_newpath);

    pthread_mutex_unlock(&status_lock);
    return 0;
}


int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    char   *line = NULL;
    size_t  size = 0;
    ssize_t len;

    if (argc != 2 || !strcmp(argv[1], "-h") || !strcmp(argv[1], "--help")) {
        const char *argv0 = (argc > 0 && argv[0]) ? argv[0] : "(this)";
        fprintf(stderr, "\n");
        fprintf(stderr, "Usage: %s [ -h | --help ]\n", argv0);
        fprintf(stderr, "       %s STATUS-FILE\n", argv0);
        fprintf(stderr, "\n");
        fprintf(stderr, "This program maintains a pseudofile-like status file,\n");
        fprintf(stderr, "using the contents from standard input.\n");
        fprintf(stderr, "Supply an empty line to exit.\n");
        fprintf(stderr, "\n");
        return EXIT_FAILURE;
    }

    status_path = join2(argv[1], "");
    status_newpath = join2(argv[1], ".new");
    unlink(status_path);
    unlink(status_newpath);

    if (start_status_worker()) {
        fprintf(stderr, "Cannot start status worker thread: %s.\n", strerror(errno));
        return EXIT_FAILURE;
    }

    if (set_status("Empty\n")) {
        fprintf(stderr, "Cannot create initial empty status: %s.\n", strerror(errno));
        return EXIT_FAILURE;
    }

    while (1) {
        len = getline(&line, &size, stdin);
        if (len < 1)
            break;

        line[strcspn(line, "\n")] = '\0';
        if (line[0] == '\0')
            break;

        set_status("%s\n", line);
    }

    pthread_cancel(status_thread);
    pthread_join(status_thread, NULL);

    if (status_fd != -1)
        close(status_fd);

    unlink(status_path);
    unlink(status_newpath);

    return EXIT_SUCCESS;
}
```

Save the above as `server.c`, then compile using e.g.

```
gcc -Wall -Wextra -O2 server.c -lpthread -o server
```

This implements a status server, storing each line from standard input to the status file if necessary.  Supply an empty line to exit.  For example, to use the file `status` in the current directory, just run

```
./server status
```

Then, if you use another terminal window to examine the directory, you see it has a file named `status` (with typically zero size).  But, `cat status` shows you its contents; just like procfs/sysfs pseudofiles.

Note that the status file is only updated if necessary, and only for the first reader/accessor after status changes.  This keeps writer/server overhead and I/O low, even if the status changes very often.

The above example program uses a worker thread to catch the lease-break signals.  This is because pthread mutexes cannot be locked or released safely in a signal handler (`pthread_mutex_lock()` etc. are not *async-signal safe*).  The worker thread maintains its *cancelability*, so that it won't be canceled when it holds the mutex; if canceled during that time, it will be canceled after it releases the mutex.  It is careful that way.

Also, the temporary replacement file is not random, it is just the status file name with `.new` appended at end.  Anywhere on the same mount would work fine.

As long as other threads also block the lease break signal, this works fine in multithreaded programs, too.  (If you create other threads after the worker thread, they'll inherit the correct signal mask from the main thread; `start_status_worker()` sets the signal mask for the calling thread.)

I do trust the approach in the program, but there may be bugs (and perhaps even thinkos) in this implementation.  If you find any, please comment or edit.

Comment: Thanks! Don't worry about an example, my first thinking was indeed to go along what you describe as option 1 and create a tmp file in `/dev/shm` (or any directory) and then _rename_ to the target file... this should be somehow atomic I hope... and readers wouldn't see partial data...

Comment: @Emanuele: Yes, renaming a file over another is atomic in Linux. Openers see either the old file, or the new file, never a mix; and it does not affect any readers that have the old file open, they can read (and even write) to their file even afterwards.  This is because the actual file metadata and contents are the *inode*, and the names just refer to inodes.

Comment: @Emanuele: However, I decided the file lease approach is the more generally viable approach, so I wrote an example program.  It uses a helper thread to handle the lease break signals, and to update the contents whenever a reader wants the new status contents.  (After the contents have been written, readers can access it freely without incurring any work from the writer, until the next status update.  If the status changes often, and the status file is examined less often than that, this is more efficient than just saving each status!)

Comment: Thanks - I'll go with simple approach though :-)