# Make executable-embedded binary blob accessible as a filesystem file while app runs. C/C++

Tags: c++, c, linux, filesystems, embedded-resource

The expected steps is somewhat like (let's assume we only target Linux, for simplicity):

1. Embed some binary blob into an C/C++ executable at compile time. [ok, can do this].
2. When app runs embedded blobs are made available to other programs as a read-only files on a filesystem with an app defined paths and filenames (e.g. somewhere like "/tmp/my_embedded_resource.bin"). [fmemopen and then ... ?]
3. When app quits (even if it crashes) those read-only "files" (links?) are automatically removed.

So, the gist of this question is inside points (2) and (3) above.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Are you looking for something like [`libfuse`](https://github.com/libfuse/libfuse#user-content-libfuse)?

Comment: Potential duplicate: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62276058/how-do-i-expose-custom-files-similar-to-procfs-on-linux . The "files" in `/proc` are runtime-generated and cleaned up automatically.

Answer (score 1):

**Keyword**: Shared Memory Objects

Have a look at [shm_open](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/shm_open.3.html).

Answer (score 1):

What you are looking for is `FUSE` - Filesystem in Userspace.

FUSE allows you to create a file system that will be exported by the application running in the user space (no need for kernel modules).

Following is link toward the [hello world](https://github.com/libfuse/libfuse/blob/master/example/hello.c) FUSE example, and will be a good starting pint.

You will need to create custom functions as follows:

- `readdir` function should return the files that are located in the virtual directory,
- `open` and `read` should provide the content of the files
- `getattr` should provides the file attributes and
- `init` will be called by FUSE to initialize the resources for the FS

FUSE is *nix library available for Linux and macOS.